# É possível captar um item de um array json para mudar um attribute de um rect no raphaels.js?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Eu gostaria de fazer um array que pudesse servir como um banco de dados para o meu mapa representado por esses 3 retângulos. O array conterá numeros que servirão como indicadores para as cores dos retângulos, Se o item 1 do array for 0 o retangulo 1 será vermelho, se o item 2 do array for 1 o retangulo 2 será azul e se o item 3 do array for 2 o retangulo 3 será amarelo. Sei que o código pode ficar um pouco complicado, mas alguém pode me dizer se é possível usar esse array como DB da minha aplicação?

```
var r = Raphael('map', '2048', '1024');
var set = r.set();

set.push(
  r.rect(1757.6, 39.4, 18.1, 44.9),
  r.rect(1736.5, 39.4, 18.1, 44.9),
  r.rect(1715.3, 39.4, 18.1, 44.9)
);

set.attr({
  fill: '#3953A4',
  stroke: 'none'
});

var glow;
set.hover(
  function() {
    glow = this.glow({
      width: 7,
      fill: true,
      opacity: 1,
      color: '#24d'
    });
}, function() {
     glow.remove();
});
```

ta aqui o array de json

```
var quadra_a = {[
  "lote0" : "RED",
  "lote1" : "BLUE",
  "lote2" : "YELLOW"
]};
```

gostaria de saber como modificar o attr fill do mapa em rapaheljs com o item do array em json.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, você quer guardar esses dados no próprio browser?

Comment: Se você se sentir seguro com seu "DB" em memória, porque não?